# how can we achieve responsive scalling in adobe muse parallax scrolling?

Tags: scroll, adobe, parallax, muse

Wondering if this can be achieve this by adobe muse?

i was browsing the website and suddenly the following website

```
http://www.theqcamera.com
```

caught my eyes, its not the image sequence but the home page scaling to fit 100% in width and height   till we scroll down to rest of the page, can't really figure out, how it is done?

it would be really helpful , if you can guide us how to achieve this in adobe muse.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This cannot currently be achieved in adobe muse. However there are browser-width effects that can make your site have a greater impression than a standard 960px width site.

I assume that the site you referenced is written with Dreamweaver, though I am certain there are other ways as well. Recently I have been looking into Dw but there are also rumors that Muse will be integrating some scaling features in future updates.